# How to set padding between value labels and line for MPAndroidChart LineChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

When I create a line chart with values for each point, the values on the chart overlap the line, as shown in the screenshot.  Is there a function to add padding to the values to raise them up so that this doesn't happen?  I've looked all over the place for an answer to this or even someone else having the same issue and haven't found what I'm looking for.

My current chart:

[image]

Comment: you add MPAndroid charts as a library or use its compile dependency?

Comment: try this link https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/2531

Comment: That is not what I'm looking for.  That is talking about the distance between the labels on the x-axis (in my case, the times).  I'm looking to put separation between the value labels (the temperatures), and the line itself.  I am using it as a gradle dependency

Comment: when you are using library as a gradle then its impossible to change layout of library views

Comment: How can I get around that?

Comment: try to change label text size

Comment: I'm not trying to make the text smaller.  I want it to stay that size and just move away from the line

Comment: ok try this lineChart.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(-2);
and this too 
//Leave some space before the line
xAxis.setSpaceMin(50f);
//Leave some space after the line
xAxis.setSpaceMax(50f);

Comment: I don't think you understand what it is that I'm trying to do.  This has nothing to do with the X-Axis or the spacing of things on the axis.  I'm talking about the data values on the blue line.  They're intersecting the line itself, and I'm trying to move them up.  The two things you suggested have nothing to do with that based on the javadoc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out.

Based on this line in the source code:

`int valOffset = (int) (dataSet.getCircleRadius() * 1.75f);`

The padding is calculated based on the radius of the circle on the line, so my solution is to increase the size of the circle, set the outer radius to be transparent, and set the hole color to be the same as the line, which accomplishes what I want.  This may not work for everyone, depending on what you're trying to do, but it worked in my case.